# Facebook friend handling via python and GraphAPI

Tags: python, facebook

i am learning about handling the graph api in python via the FacePy module.

I am just curious as to see if it was possible to delete friends via the Graph API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of possible misuse that might happen, feature like deleting friends via Facebook is not available. You can although send [Friend Requests](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/friends/) but the app should not use this feature to encourage users to friend other users that they are not connected to in real life.